# SOAP Request and Response not working

Tags: php, xml, soap

i want to make a SOAP request to the server. But i'm struggling with an error.
This is how the XML should look like:

```
<ExternalOrder Ref="85" Version="2">
   <Orders>
            <Order Operation="Add" Client="1">
                <Item Operation="Add">
                    <ItemId>244</ItemId>
                    <Description>coke</Description>
                    <Quantity>2</Quantity>
                    <Price>1.75</Price>
                </Item>
            </Order>
    </Orders>
</ExternalOrder>
```

Here is my PHP code:
http://11.30.11.151/ProxyWebService/ProxyService.asmx?WSDL', array('trace' => true));

```
$result = $client->__soapCall('AddOrder', array(
    'ExternalOrder' => [
        'Orders' => [
            'Order' => [
                'Item' => [
                    'ItemId' => '244',
                    'Description' => 'coke',
                    'Quantity' => '2',
                    'Price' => '1.75'
                ],
            ]
        ] 
    ]        
));

?>
```

Server response: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: It's too specific. You'll have to debug your web service. Examine the SoapFault returned, maybe there is some more detailed stack trace from service.